# Maintain a responsive user interface with backgroundWorker and heavy animation

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have a C# application (winforms and wpf, but for this question I'm focusing on the winforms one) where a backgroundWorker is used to work on a data set, and the call to ProgressChanged which then calls the form Refresh method to force a repaint. This then paints a bunch of ellipses based on the current frame of the data set.

A given frame may involve drawing anywhere between zero and several hundred ellipses.

In addition, I have a slider control that allows the user to adjust the playback rate (basically the thread.sleep value within the loop.)

When the user sets the sleep value too low, sometimes the repainting methods get queued up, and the UI becomes unresponsive. (This depends on the number of ellipses in the frame, and the speed of the computer. And the delay is 100% with the repainting on the UI, not with any other processing, which is basically just incrementing a counter and setting a label text.)

I would like to be able to detect the queuing up and automatically adjust the speed slider to accommodate a larger data set and/or slower computer. How can I tell if the UI thread is backed up with multiple calls to Map_Paint?

Current code (paraphrased):

```
public Map()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  _worker = new BackgroundWorker();
  _worker.DoWork += _worker_DoWork;
  _worker.ProgressChanged += _worker_ProgressChanged;
  _worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
}

private void _worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    _frameCount = _frames.FrameCount();
    // For this specific example, _frameCount may be around 30000-40000
    for (var i = 0; i < _frameCount; i++)
    {
      var f = _frames.Frame(i + 1);
      _worker.ReportProgress(i, f);
      Thread.Sleep(_tickCount);
      _suspend.WaitOne(); // Used to Pause the playback
    }
}
void _worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
  // set some variables according to state and progresspercentage snipped here
  // ...

  // I would like to detect at this point whether the screen repainting is backed up
  // and if so, adjust the value of _tickCount to slow down the program.

  this.Refresh();
}

private void Map_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)

{
    // Lots of ellipsis drawing stuff here
    // Maybe 0-1000 ellipses drawn per cycle.
}

private void tbSpeed_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // This is the Scroll event for the slider.
  // Value range is 10-300
  // The slider becomes unresponsive when the UI thread backs up.
  // I'd like to detect the back up and override the value of _tickCount
  _tickCount = tbSpeed.Value;
}
```

Comment: The first step in addressing a problem such as you describe is to lower the thread priority for the worker thread, to ensure the UI thread (which runs at "normal" priority) will always get precedence, if it has work to do. Note that WM_PAINT messages are not real messages; Windows generates them as needed when the message queue is empty and there is drawing to be done. So you can't actually check to see if WM_PAINT messages are backing up (they never do). You can check the message queue length itself with native code, but IMHO that should not be needed here.

Comment: Good suggestion Peter. I'll give that a try too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private static object _lock = new object();
private static int _queuedCount = 0;

public Map()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  _worker = new BackgroundWorker();
  _worker.DoWork += _worker_DoWork;
  _worker.ProgressChanged += _worker_ProgressChanged;
  _worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
}

private void _worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    _frameCount = _frames.FrameCount();
    // For this specific example, _frameCount may be around 30000-40000
    for (var i = 0; i < _frameCount; i++)
    {
      var f = _frames.Frame(i + 1);
      lock(_lock)
      {
          _queuedCount++;
      }
      _worker.ReportProgress(i, f);
      Thread.Sleep(_tickCount);
      _suspend.WaitOne(); // Used to Pause the playback
    }
}
void _worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if (_queuedCount > 1)
      //now queue is building up

  this.Refresh();
  lock(_lock)
  {
      _queuedCount--;
  }
}
```